# How can i set text align from bottom to top in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a background image a and i want to right the text **align from bottom to top**.Just like the image showed as following. In my case, the background image is fixed, i cannot rotate it,so i just tried to rotate text!However, i cannot align it well!

Background Image(**cannot be rotated**)

[image: background]

**The result i want**(just like left align,center align and rotate -90)

[image]

I tried this code,but not work! I think the reason is the rotation center!

```
Text {
            text: name;
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter;  // Centering text
            anchors.left: parent.left;
            anchors.leftMargin: 18;
            rotation: -90
        }
```

If i rotate the background image 90 degree. Then apply my code and rotate the content(background and text) will get good result! However i cannot rotate the background image! How can i set text align from bottom to top in qml?

Comment: _background image can't be rotated_ .. why?

Comment: Why don't you anchor to `parent.bottom` if you want to align your text to bottom ? Why `verticalCenter` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchoring with rotation might be at odds to manage. You can make it simple:

```
 Rectangle{
    color: "grey"
    width: 50
    height: 300
    Text{
     //1. Place Text box symmetrically below background, edge to edge
        width: parent.height
        height: parent.width
        y:parent.height
        text: "TableA Description 15"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
     // comment below 2 lines to see how it looks before rotation 
     //2 pivot top left of text box and rotate text -90
        transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
        rotation: -90
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Transform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rotation.html) provides more complex transformations for the QML item. In your case, check demo in below, it shows `Text` rotate itself -90 degree. and you can adjust the rotate point by setting the `origin.x origin.y` properties.

```
Rectangle{
    width: 100; height: 300
    color: "lightblue"
    Text{
        id: test
        text: "TestMe"
        transform: [
            Rotation {
                origin.x: test.paintedWidth/2; origin.y: test.paintedWidth/2; angle: -90
            },
            Translate{
                y: (test.parent.height - test.paintedWidth)/2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried.But the problem is difficult to find the center point